# Proceso animación javascript por pasos

Tags: javascript, html, css

He trazado la pantalla de una máquina en css y html pero quiero darle unas animaciones ordenadas. Yo e creado animaciones con javascript y css pero no se como hacer para que primero actue una, seguido otra, etc..

```
$('#fondoSoftware').waypoint(function(){
        $('.barraNaranja').css("height","130px");
        $('.barraNaranja').css("transition","6.1s");
        },{
          offset: '60%'
        });
        $('.counter').counterUp({
            delay: 10,
            time: 5000
        });
        $('.jcm').counterUp({
            delay: 10,
            time: 5000
        });
        $('.milisegundos').counterUp({
            delay: 10,
            time: 5000
        });

        $('#fondoSoftware').waypoint(function(){
          $('.btn1Hz').css("background","linear-gradient(150deg,#0fe097 15%,#76d5b5 70%,#0fe097 94%)");
          $('.btn1Hz').css("transition","0.5s");
          },{
            offset: '60%'
        });

        $('#fondoSoftware').waypoint(function(){
          $('.2hz').css("background","#b5bdff");
          $('.2hz').css("transition","0.9s");
          },{
            offset: '60%',
        });

        $('#fondoSoftware').waypoint(function(){
          $('.2hz').css("background","#b5bdff");
          $('.2hz').css("transition","0.9s");
          },{
            offset: '60%',
        });

        $('#fondoSoftware').waypoint(function(){
          $('.btnMax1').css("background","rgb(181, 189, 255)");
          $('.btnMax1').css("transition-delay","0.9s");
          $('.btnMax12').css("background","#566ae5");
          },{
            offset: '60%',
        });
      });
```

Comment: mira a ver si el metodo waypoint tiene para pasar como parametro una funcion de callback . o usa una promesa.

Comment: Podrías si no usar la función **animate()** de Jquery, que si que tiene callback.

Comment: pero el waypoint lo utilice para que empiece la animación una vez llega a ese punto

Comment: ¿Podrías crear un [mcve] añadiendo el HTML/CSS? Así podríamos ver el problema directamente en la pregunta y ayudarte mejor. También sería bueno que aclares cómo lo quieres solucionar, por una parte dices que quieres las animaciones cuando se llegue a un punto, pero por otro dices que quieres ejecutarlas una seguida de otra.